# Regex to match variable length, spaces and special chars?

Tags: regex

I've got some strings like so

```
2020-03-05 11:23:25: zone 10 type Interior name 'Study PIR'
2020-03-05 11:57:15: zone 13 type Entry/Exit 1 name 'Front Door'
```

I've got the below regex that works for the first string, however I'm not sure how to get the product group to match the full group "Entry/Exit 1"  The number can range from 1 - 100

```
(?<Date>[0-9]{4}-[0-2][1-9]-[0-2][1-9]) (?<Time>2[0-3]|[01][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]): (?<msgType>\w+) (?<id>[0-9]+) (?<type>\w+) (?<product>\w+) \w+ (?<deviceName>'([^']*)')
```

Any ideas how I can modify this to match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `product` group pattern should be

```
(?<product>\w+(?:\/\w+\s+\d+)?)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/csk17V/1)

**Details**

- `\w+` - 1+ word chars
- `(?:\/\w+\s+\d+)?` - an optional sequence of

  - `\/` - a `/` char
  - `\w+` - 1+ word chars
  - `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
  - `\d+` - 1+ digits.

If the format is unknown, or does not fit the above description, just use `(?<product>.*?)`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/csk17V/2).